# How do I use Java stream collect to create a map with a String as the key instead of object?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following...

```
public Map<Object, Integer> getRankings(){
    Stream<String> stream = votes.stream();
    Map<Object, Integer> map = stream
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum));
    return Vote.sortByValues(map);
}
```

But I would like the return type to be `Map<String, Integer>` instead. How do I coerce the `Object` to a `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a `Stream<String>`, it can be inferred by just declaring the map with a key type of `String`:

```
Map<String, Integer> map =
    stream.collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem in this:

```
public Map<String, Integer> getRankings(){
    Stream<String> stream = votes.stream();
    Map<String, Integer> map = stream
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum));
    return Vote.sortByValues(map);
}
```